# How to generate a diagram as below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am a (La)TeX newbie and I have found the following graphic in a [document](http://math.umn.edu/~poli0048/CameraModels.pdf):
[image: camera projection model with latex]

I am quite sure it was generated by LaTeX code since you can select every bit of text in the original file.

I am not asking for complete code (though it would be nice), but some starters e.g. what packages to use and what features of such packages. My initial searches indicate TikZ may be appropriate.

Comment: Might not be TikZ, since the figure fonts (DejaVu Sans?) are different than the body of the document. I'd start by doing enough TikZ to make a triangle with filled circles at two corners, and possibly a trapezoid for the image plane.

Comment: Also, you can create images in another application without the text and then use LaTeX to add just the text labels (e.g. Inkscape). Or you can draw the image in another application and export code for one of various drawing programmes (e.g. Inkscape). Or you can use a programme to draw diagrams which can be integrated into TeX (e.g. Asymptote.)

Comment: Why don't you email the author and ask?

Comment: Unlikely to be generated when compiling the document: the document is compiled with pdfTeX but the truetype fonts from the diagrams are embedded as subsets. If I remember correctly and things haven't changed, pdfTeX cannot subset truetype fonts. Also, it would be a weird choice to use that font mixture on purpose. (Of course, people make weird choices and as much about fonts as everything else.)

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96074/more-elegant-way-to-achieve-this-same-camera-perspective-projection-model