# How to modify this TikZ code to draw in another locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96074/more-elegant-way-to-achieve-this-same-camera-perspective-projection-model) nice code to draw a pinhole camera model.

I am new to TikZ and I would like to modify the code in order to draw the square pixels starting from the `v` axis instead of the `y` axis (in the linked figure).

Unfortunately, I don't get the logic of how he is able to draw the square pixels in his figure. How can I do this?

The relevant code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Picture's vectors definition
\def\xOne{1}
\def\xTwo{0.5}
\def\yOne{0}
\def\yTwo{-1.3}
\def\zOne{-1}
\def\zTwo{0.5}

%% PROJECTION PLANE
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,draw=gray!70,opacity=0.8] (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo+1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+1.5*\xOne+1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo+1.5*\xTwo+1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne+1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo+1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo);

% PIXEL POSITION
\draw[thin,gray!70] (3*\zOne,3*\zTwo+0.75) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.19*\yOne,-0.19*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, basically you want the little "pixels" to continue on that horizontal line and reach the other side where the axis is located?

Comment: I would like to start the drawing of the little "pixels" from the left `v` axis instead of the `y` axis in the current full code (more horizontal pixels). The rest is good.

Comment: To be quite honest, I think the code is overly complicated for what it needs to do...

Comment: Reproducing part of the picture leaves us asking, which `v` axis?

Comment: I would like to start the drawing of the pixel from the uv axis (the green dashed line axis) More horizontal pixels to the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than tangling with the existing code, I decided to redraw the picture using `tikz-3dplot`.

I tweaked the arrows a little using `arrows.meta` and used `backgrounds` for convenience. The code *should* be easier to understand and modify. At least, so goes the theory. Your kilometres may, of course, vary.

The only complication, really, is that you need to mentally swap the `y` and `z` axes because `tikz-3dplot` really, really wants the `z` axis to go up or down the page. To help me manage this, I used

```
\draw [help lines] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$} (0,0,0) -- (0,7,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$} (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=north]{$z$} (-2,7,0) -- (2,7,0);
```

while drawing the picture and then commented this and added the actual axes labels etc. at the end.

I also used

```
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d} \node [red, font=\scriptsize] at (\i) {\i};
```

to track the coordinates I placed at each corner of the grey box.

Both of these devices remain, commented in the code below for information. To use them, you'd probably want to also comment the actual axes and labels to avoid confusion. That is, comment the line

```
  \draw [thick, ->, every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt}] (o) node [anchor=north west] {$F_c$} (o) edge node [pos=1, anchor=north east] {$z_c$} ++(0,1,0) edge node [pos=1, anchor=north] {$y_c$} ++(0,0,1) -- ++(1,0,0) node [anchor=north west] {$x_c$};
```

The rest is relatively straightforward, if a little tedious. It could no doubt be made more efficient, but is, I think, nonetheless, significantly more efficient than the original code.

The result is not pixel-identical so may need a little tweaking to suit your purposes, preferences and/or tastes.

[image: pinhole camera]

Code:

```
% ail-wneud y llun o gwestiwn perr0: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96074/
% côd newydd
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{-60}{-35}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    tdplot_main_coords,
    >=Stealth,
    my dashed/.style={dashed, thick, ->, shorten >=-15pt, shorten <=-15pt, every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize}},
    my box/.style={thin, gray!70},
    my blue/.style={blue, line cap=round, -{Triangle[width=3*#1]}, line width=#1, shorten >=#1*1.75pt, every node/.append style={fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1*3.5pt, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt}},
    my label/.append style={midway, font=\scriptsize},
    my vectors/.style={green!50!black, {Stealth[scale=.75]}-{Stealth[scale=.75]}},
    my red/.style={thick, red, line cap=round},
    my grey/.style={gray!70},
    description/.style={draw=gray!70, thick, line cap=round, every node/.style={align=center, font=\scriptsize\sffamily, anchor=north}},
  ]
%   \draw [help lines] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$} (0,0,0) -- (0,7,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$} (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=north]{$z$} (-2,7,0) -- (2,7,0);
  \draw [my grey] (0,4,0) -- (0,7,0) (-2,7,0) -- (2,7,0);
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0,0);
  \path [draw=gray!70, text=gray, fill=gray!20, opacity=0.8, text opacity=1] (-1.5,4,1.75) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,0,-3.5) coordinate (b) -- ++(3,0,0) coordinate (c) -- ++(0,0,3.5) coordinate (d) -- cycle node [pos=.95, above, sloped, anchor=south west] {$z=f$} ;
%   \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d} \node [red, font=\scriptsize] at (\i) {\i};
  \draw [my grey] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2);
  \draw [thick, ->, every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt}] (o) node [anchor=north west] {$F_c$} (o) edge node [pos=1, anchor=north east] {$z_c$} ++(0,1,0) edge node [pos=1, anchor=north] {$y_c$} ++(0,0,1) -- ++(1,0,0) node [anchor=north west] {$x_c$};
  \draw [my box] (a) ++(0,0,-2.25) coordinate (p1) -- ++(2.25,0,0) coordinate (p2) -- ++(0,0,-1.25) coordinate (p3);
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,8} \draw [my box] (p1) ++(\i*.25,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-.25);
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} \draw [my box] (p2) ++(0,0,-\i*.25) -- ++(-.25,0,0);
  \draw [my box] (p1) ++(0,0,-.25) -- ++(2,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-1);
  \draw [my dashed, cyan] ($(b)!1/2!(c)$) -- ($(d)!1/2!(a)$) node [below=15pt, anchor=north] {$y$};
  \draw [my dashed, cyan] ($(b)!1/2!(a)$) -- ($(d)!1/2!(c)$) node [above right=17pt, anchor=north west] {$x$};
  \draw [my dashed, green!50!black, <->] (a) node [below=15pt, anchor=north] {$v$} -- (b) -- (c) node [above right=17pt, anchor=north west] {$u$};
  \path [green!50!black, every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0pt}] (p2) node [above right, anchor=south west] {$(u,v)$};
  \path (p2) ++(-.125,0,0) coordinate (q2) ++(0,0,-.125) coordinate (r2);
  \draw [my blue=1] ($($(a)!1/2!(b)$)+($(q2)-(p1)$)$) coordinate (s2) -- (r2) node (d1) {};
  \scoped[on background layer]{\draw [my blue=1.75] ($($1.75*($(s2)-(0,4,0)$)$)+(0,7,0)$) -- ++($1.75*($(r2)-(s2)$)$) node (d2) [label={[label distance=-20pt]above:{$P=(X,Y,Z)$}}] {};}
  \draw [my vectors] (0,4,.1) -- ($(s2)+(0,0,.1)$) node [below, my label, sloped] {$\vec{u}$};
  \draw [my vectors] (-.1,4,0) -- ($(q2)-(s2)+(-.1,4,0)$) node [left, my label] {$\vec{v}$};
  \draw [my red] (o) -- (d1.center);
  \scoped[on background layer]{\draw [my red] (d1.center) -- (d2.center);}
  \path [description] (0,4,0) [out=-95, in=95] to (-.75,4,.25) node {ponto\\principal} (0,6.5,0) [out=-95, in=95] to (-.75,6.5,.25) node {eixo\\\'otico};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel a little bit stupid now. I managed to tweak the original code to have what I want.

Basically, I modified the original starting coordinate:

```
(3*\zOne,3*\zTwo+0.75)
```

and copy-pasted the pattern to draw the "pixels":

```
++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo)
```

The figure:
[image: modified figure]

The corresponding code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Picture's vectors definition
\def\xOne{1}
\def\xTwo{0.5}
\def\yOne{0}
\def\yTwo{-1.3}
\def\zOne{-1}
\def\zTwo{0.5}

% CAMERA COORDINATE SYSTEM
%\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (\xOne,\xTwo) node[anchor=north]{$x$};
%\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (\yOne,\yTwo) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
%\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (\zOne,\zTwo) node[anchor=north,yshift=-2pt,xshift=3pt]{$z$};
\draw[very thick,->] (-\zOne/2,-\zTwo/2) -- (-\zOne/2+\xOne,-\zTwo/2+\xTwo) node[anchor=north west, xshift=-3pt,font=\footnotesize]{$x_c$};
\draw[very thick,->] (-\zOne/2,-\zTwo/2) -- (-\zOne/2+\yOne,-\zTwo/2+\yTwo) node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$y_c$};
\draw[very thick,->] (-\zOne/2,-\zTwo/2) -- (\zOne/2,\zTwo/2) node[anchor=north,yshift=-2pt,xshift=3pt,font=\footnotesize]{$z_c$};
\draw (-\zOne/2,-\zTwo/2) node[anchor=north west,font=\footnotesize]{$\mathcal{F}_c$};

% CAMERA AXIS ELONGATION
\draw[very thin,solid] (-\zOne/2-2*\xOne,-\zTwo/2-2*\xTwo) -- (-\zOne/2+2*\xOne,-\zTwo/2+2*\xTwo); % x elongation
\draw[very thin,solid] (3*\zOne,3*\zTwo) -- (6*\zOne,6*\zTwo); % optical axis behind projection plane

% REFERENCE LINES
%\draw[thin,dashed] (1.4*\xOne-\zOne/2,1.4*\xTwo-\zTwo/2) -- (6*\zOne+1.4*\xOne,6*\zTwo+1.4*\xTwo); % object x position
\draw[very thin,solid] (6*\zOne-2*\xOne,6*\zTwo-2*\xTwo) -- (6*\zOne+2*\xOne,6*\zTwo+2*\xTwo) node[anchor=west]{}; %object z position

% WORLD OBJECT
\draw[-latex,line width=3pt,blue,line cap=round] (6*\zOne+1.4*\xOne,6*\zTwo+1.4*\xTwo) -- (6*\zOne+1.4*\xOne,6*\zTwo+1.4*\xTwo+1.1) node[anchor=south,font=\footnotesize]{$ P = (X,Y,Z) $};
\node[circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.2cm,fill=blue] (object) at (6*\zOne+1.4*\xOne,6*\zTwo+1.4*\xTwo+1.1) {};

% PROJECTION LINE BEHIND PROJECTION PLANE
\draw[thick,solid,red] (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.7*\xTwo+0.69) -- (6*\zOne+1.4*\xOne,6*\zTwo+1.4*\xTwo+1.1);

%% PROJECTION PLANE
\filldraw[fill=gray!20,draw=gray!70,opacity=0.8] (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo+1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+1.5*\xOne+1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo+1.5*\xTwo+1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne+1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo+1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo);

% PLOJECTION PLANE COORDINATE SYSTEM u,v
\draw[->,thick,green!70!black,dashed] (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+2*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo+2*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo)
     node[anchor=north west, xshift=-3pt,font=\footnotesize]{$u$};
\draw[->,thick,green!70!black,dashed] (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo-1.5*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-1.5*\xOne-1.5*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1.5*\xTwo+2*\yTwo)
     node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$v$};

% PROJECTION PLANE COORDINATE SYSTEM x,y
\draw[->,thick,cyan,dashed] (3*\zOne-2*\xOne,3*\zTwo-2*\xTwo) -- (3*\zOne+2*\xOne,3*\zTwo+2*\xTwo)
     node[anchor=north west, xshift=-3pt,font=\footnotesize]{$x$};
\draw[->,thick,cyan,dashed] (3*\zOne-2*\yOne,3*\zTwo-2*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+2*\yOne,3*\zTwo+2*\yTwo)
     node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$y$};

% PROJECTION  OBJECT
\draw[-latex,line width=1.5pt,blue,line cap=round] (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.69*\xTwo) -- (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.69*\xTwo+0.69);
\node[circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.1cm,fill=blue] (object) at (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.7*\xTwo+0.69) {};

% PIXEL OBJECT
\filldraw[red,opacity=0.6] (3*\zOne+6*0.105*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.75+6*0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo);

% PROJECTION LINE IN FRONT OF PROJECTION PLANE
\draw[thick,solid,red] (-\zOne/2,-\zTwo/2) -- (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.7*\xTwo+0.69);

% OPTICAL AXIS IN FRONT OF PROJECTION PLANE
\draw[thin,solid] (0,0) -- (3*\zOne,3*\zTwo);

% ANNOTATIONS
% z = f
\draw (3*\zOne-1*\xOne+1.3*\yOne,3*\zTwo-1*\xTwo+1.3*\yTwo) node[gray!70,rotate=28] {$ z = f $};
% bar(u)
\draw[to-to, green!70!black] (3*\zOne+0.13*\xOne+0.08*\yOne,3*\zTwo+0.13*\xTwo+0.08*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne+0.7*\xOne+0.08*\yOne,3*\zTwo+0.7*\xTwo+0.08*\yTwo) node[midway,anchor=north west,xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt,font=\scriptsize] {$ \bar{u} $};
% bar(v)
\draw[to-to, green!70!black] (3*\zOne-0.1*\xOne-0.04*\yOne,3*\zTwo-0.1*\xTwo-0.04*\yTwo) -- (3*\zOne-0.1*\xOne,3*\zTwo-0.1*\xTwo+0.75) node[midway,anchor=east,xshift=2pt,font=\scriptsize] {$ \bar{v} $};
% (u,v)
\node[green!70!black,anchor=west,font=\scriptsize] at (3*\zOne+0.69*\xOne,3*\zTwo+0.7*\xTwo+0.69) {$ (u,v) $};
% principal point
\draw[very thin] (3*\zOne-0.02*\xOne+0.02*\yOne,3*\zTwo-0.02*\xTwo+0.02*\yTwo) .. controls (3*\zOne-0.1*\xOne+0.3*\yOne,3*\zTwo-0.1*\xTwo+0.3*\yTwo) and (3*\zOne-0.3*\xOne+0.1*\yOne,3*\zTwo-0.3*\xTwo+0.1*\yTwo) ..  (3*\zOne-0.6*\xOne+0.4*\yOne,3*\zTwo-0.6*\xTwo+0.4*\yTwo) node[anchor=north,align=center,font=\sffamily\scriptsize] {ponto \\ principal};
% optical axis
\draw[very thin] (5.5*\zOne-0.02*\xOne+0.02*\yOne,5.5*\zTwo-0.02*\xOne+0.02*\yOne) .. controls (5.5*\zOne-0.1*\xOne+0.3*\yOne,5.5*\zTwo-0.1*\xTwo+0.3*\yTwo) and (5.5*\zOne-0.3*\xOne+0.1*\yOne,5.5*\zTwo-0.3*\xTwo+0.1*\yTwo) ..  (5.5*\zOne-0.6*\xOne+0.4*\yOne,5.5*\zTwo-0.6*\xTwo+0.4*\yTwo) node[anchor=north,align=center,font=\sffamily\scriptsize] {eixo \\ \'otico};

% PIXEL POSITION
\draw[thin,gray!70] (4.375*\zOne,3.1*\zTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) --  ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\yOne,-0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(0.21*\xOne,0.21*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.21*\yOne,-0.21*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo) -- ++(-0.105*\xOne,-0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(-0.19*\yOne,-0.19*\yTwo) -- ++(0.105*\xOne,0.105*\xTwo) -- ++(0.105*\yOne,0.105*\yTwo);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If someone was about to post a more elaborate answer or a better way to draw the picture, I will wait before picking the right answer.