# Draw two opposing planes setting

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to draw something like this:
[image]

I have the image above.

I found something similar to this drawing here:
[How to modify this TikZ code to draw in another locations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323764/how-to-modify-this-tikz-code-to-draw-in-another-locations)

But I cant reproduce the first image.. Can someone help me at least create something similar to this graph please?

Comment: You can draw such things along the lines of the answer you link. The problem for anyone trying to answer this is that it is hard to impossible to infer the 3d coordinates from the picture you show. Could you perhaps provide us with the 3d coordinates of the various points?

Comment: I don't have them either.. But I guess the relative coordinates are not difficult to guess..

Comment: Well, if you guess them and post them here, somebody will surely draw the graph for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question but may help you to set up things in such a way that achieving what you want becomes more straightforward. Your setting can be transformed in such a way that `O=(6,0,0)`, `O'=(0,6,0)` and `P0=(0,0,0)`. This has the advantage that the perpendicular planes can be drawn with the `3d` library (which has a documentation in the latest update of the pgfmanual, yay!!!).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\path (6,0,0) coordinate (O) (0,6,0) coordinate (O') (0,0,0) coordinate (X1);
\draw (O) -- (X1) coordinate[pos=2/3] (X3) coordinate[pos=5/6] (X2) 
-- (O') -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
\draw (-2,-1.2) rectangle (2,1.2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=4]
\draw (-2,-1.2) rectangle (2,1.2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to work in your coordinate system but this is somewhat more effort. Of course, may proposal may not help much if your coordinate system has the virtue that the additional stuff you want to draw becomes particularly simple.